# Using values from a tool parameter defined as multiple value

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I am trying to use values from a parameter that accepts multiple value and use the in the iteration but am getting an error. I have failed to understand where the error is coming from because the code was working fine. The values are obtained from the interface below
[image: the value that the user chooses]

The user can select one or more values.The code is below

```
import arcpy,os

inputraster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
sea_level = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
clipraster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
outputfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
valuelist = [x.strip() for x in sea_level.split(";")]
for value in valuelist:

 arcpy.Clip_management(inputraster,"#",clipraster,fc,"#","ClippingGeometry","MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
        clip_raster = arcpy.Raster(clipraster)
        floodedarea = os.path.join(outputfolder + "floods" + str(value))
        areasbelow = clip_raster <= value
        areasbelow.save(floodedarea)
        arcpy.AddMessage(areasbelow)
```

---

Edit:

The error message:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset 1 does not exist or is not supported
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: `ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset 1 does not exist or is not supported` thats the error i receive. @BERA

Comment: From what I can see you have not defined the variables rasterclip, clipraster and fc so  `arcpy.Clip_management(rasterclip,"#",clipraster,fc...` will fail.

Comment: @BERA all the variables have been defined in the code but still am getting an error

Comment: Not in the code you are showing here. I would look at them first when you are getting this error.

Comment: @stasha for us to help you, you need to be listing all the variables,  it's not enough you saying they are all declared, it is highly likely your problem may stem from invalid syntax in variables we cannot see as the code you _are_ showing appears OK.

Comment: @HORNBYDD okey i will edit the orginal code to show the variables

Comment: Are the order of parameters in your code the same as your interface? The picture seems to suggest that sea level is parameter 3. Your code suggests 'clipraster' is parameter 3?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain all information about the problem, including the error(s) you are receiving.  It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: i edited the original question and even added the error that i get...it only one line of error that i get..@Vince

Comment: Please include AddMessage statements before you use the variable values obtained from your tool dialog so that we can see what each is set to before you run the Clip.  Also, your indentation looks to be astray so can you check again that you are running exactly the code that you present, please?

Comment: @ PolyGeo I solved the problem by changing the `GetParameterAsText` to `GetParameter`